# In YOLO V7, Can I combine two separate trained model (weight files) to detect different images?

Tags: pytorch, classification, object-detection, yolo

Let's say, I have trained a custom model with **500 images of Apple**. I have got a **best.pt** file which can detect apple very well. Now, I have trained another yolov7 model, with **500 images of Orange**, and have got another **best.pt** file which can detect Orange very well. Now I want to combine that two .pt file together, so that if I provide both **orange and apple image,** then that **combined .pt** file can detect them all. Is that possible, or how can I solve this issue. Any other way, to do that instead of training a model with two types of images.
Please, experts asking for your help.

So far, I have just trained two models, but don't know how to combine and make the models as one.